# I need help to use OAuth 2 to connect an API

Tags: rest, oauth, request

I'm trying to connect to an API provided by the French administration [PISTE](https://developer.aife.economie.gouv.fr/en) via OAuth 2 and I can't get through. My final goal is to get legal information on notebook (via urllib3) from LEGIFRANCE and JUDILIBRE API but I can't even manage to request a token with cURL.

Steps:

1. Create an account and edit my application

   - [user guide](https://piste.gouv.fr/en/help-center/guide)
   - To have access to LEGIFRANCE and JUDILIBRE it's necessary to select the API **and** agreed with the ToS

     [screen : when it's done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgqTd.jpg)
2. Trying to get a token

   In a bash script, I tried this :

   ```bash
     # auth_url='https://sandbox-oauth.piste.gouv.fr/api/oauth/authorize'

     token_url='https://sandbox-oauth.piste.gouv.fr/api/oauth/token'

     client_id='here_is_my_ID'
     key='here_is_my_key'

     curl -k -v -H 'content-type: application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='$client_id'&client_secret='$key'&scope=openid' -X POST $token_url
   ```

   The server answer:

   ```html
   <TITLE>401 Authorization Required</TITLE>
   </HEAD><BODY>
   <H1>Authorization Required</H1>
   This server could not verify that you
   are authorized to access the document
   requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
   credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
   browser doesn't understand how to supply
   the credentials required.<P>
   ```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: In many cases the client_id and client_secret need to be provided as HTTP Basic authentication instead of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, it was a command issue. This works :

```
curl -k -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
> -d grant_type=client_credentials \
> -d client_id=_here_my_id_ \
> -d client_secret=_here_my_key_ \
> -d scope=openid \
> -X POST https://oauth.piste.gouv.fr/api/oauth/token
```